# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed while retrieving data using datareader from stored procedure

Tags: c#, wcf, dataset, subsonic, datareader

Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.
while invoking the data from stored procedure by using datareader  the while loop was terminated without executing,the stored procedure from  subsonic dal(wcf)

```
using (IDataReader reader = SPs.GetProductsSearch(ProductName,PageSize, PageIndex).GetReader())
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductId"] = reader["ProductId"];
                dr["ProductPriceId"] = reader["ProductPriceId"];
                dr["Name"] = reader["Name"];
                dr["UrlRewrite"] = reader["UrlRewrite"];
                dr["Description"] = reader["Description"];
                dr["Price"] = reader["Price"];
                dr["Size"] = reader["Size"];
                dr["Stock"] = reader["Stock"];
                dr["Weight"] = reader["Weight"];
                dr["MediaFilename"] = reader["MediaFilename"];
                dr["ThumbnailFilename"] = reader["ThumbnailFilename"];
                dr["ProductName"] = reader["ProductName"];
                dr["ProductDescription"] = reader["ProductDescription"];
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;

    }`
 public static StoredProcedure GetProductsSearch(string name, int? PageSize, int? PageIndex)
    {
        SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = new SubSonic.StoredProcedure("Test_Get_Products_Search", DataService.GetInstance("Echemist"), "dbo");

        sp.Command.AddParameter("@SearchName", name, DbType.AnsiString, null, null);        

        sp.Command.AddParameter("@PageSize", PageSize, DbType.Int32, 0, 10);

        sp.Command.AddParameter("@PageIndex", PageIndex, DbType.Int32, 0, 10);

        return sp;
    }

    //ProductId stored procedure------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static StoredProcedure GetProductsByProductId(int ProductId)
    {
        SubSonic.StoredProcedure sp = new SubSonic.StoredProcedure("Get_ProductsByProductId", DataService.GetInstance("Echemist"), "dbo");

        sp.Command.AddParameter("@ProductId", ProductId, DbType.Int32, null, null);

        return sp;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Or adding try-catch blocks to see if there was an error further down stream?

Comment: Am getting this exception "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed." @Tim